# Change razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

How can I change razor syntax in RazorEngine?

I need to use specific keyword instead of`"@"` symbol.

For example: `$$Model.someField` instead of `@Model.someField`. (`"$$"` instead of `"@"`).

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the reason for wanting the change?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: have a look [here] http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/view-engine-with-dynamic-view-location

Comment: In case this is the reason for wanting to do this, you can output an "@" with `@@` or `@Html.Raw("@")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Razor is not really designed in a way to do it. Basically (Microsoft.AspNet.)Razor has some specially written parsers which handle "@" in a special manner (by switching parsers). This means the languages (C#, Html in this case) itself need to be compatible with this procedure as well!

If you want to replace "@" with something else you need to rewrite the Razor Parsers. This is possible, but at this point you already implemented the hardest part of Razor yourself...

The real question you should ask yourself (or answer here) is: Why you want to do it? It is not as trivial as one would think, I was at this point before.

As freedomn-m suggested you should use @Html.Raw("@") or @@ if you need to output a "@".

matthid
 - a RazorEngine contributor